# installed ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets, but i don't have _rfce

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

i used _rfce 2days ago, but it disappeared suddenly...

i installed ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets v4.1.0

and this is not disable.

also nothing have _blah _blah..

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same happened to me. Apparently there was an update that changed things a bit. I went back to version 3.1.1.
In the last 10 days there have been at least 6 updates. It uses version 3.1.1 which is the one that works well.

Comment: How to back to 3.1.1 ver ??.. ㅠㅠ

Comment: You can downgrade the extension by, Searching for the extension and right click on the extension list, then click (Install Another Version...)  and install the preferred version.

Comment: wow...., thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Comment: works as aspected

Answer (score 14):

From version 4, they removed the underscore snippets, and provides options to customize the behavior of the snippets.

If you don't want import React on top.

1. Open your settings.json, and add the following:

```
"reactSnippets.settings.importReactOnTop": false
```

Now, you can just type `rfce` without the underscore.

Comment: This solution works for me. Don't forget to restart.